# Is there a way to search date for the angular material table

Tags: angular-material, angular-material-table, angular15

`<mat-form-field class="searchbar" appearance="outline"> <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Search ..." #input />`
this is my search bar using matInput.

`applyFilter(event: Event) { const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value; this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase(); }`
this is my search filter function.

Isit able to search date format like 20/02/2024 and the table will show based on the date input without using datepicker.

[image: Example of searching date format]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can just add the `filterPredicate` with the condition to check the formatted date.

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: any, filter: string) => {
  console.log(data, filter, format(data.bookingDate, 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
  return (
    data.name.indexOf(filter) != -1 ||
    format(new Date(data.bookingDate), 'dd/mm/yyyy').indexOf(filter) != -1
  );
};
```

I am using an external package `date-fns` to format the date before doing the comparison!

full code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
function randomDate(start: any = new Date(2012, 0, 1), end: any = new Date()) {
  return new Date(
    start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime())
  );
}

const ELEMENT_DATA = [
  { name: 'Hydrogen', bookingDate: randomDate() },
  { name: 'Helium', bookingDate: randomDate() },
  { name: 'Lithium', bookingDate: randomDate() },
  { name: 'Beryllium', bookingDate: randomDate() },
  { name: 'Boron', bookingDate: randomDate() },
  { name: 'Carbon', bookingDate: randomDate() },
  { name: 'Nitrogen', bookingDate: randomDate() },
  { name: 'Oxygen', bookingDate: randomDate() },
  { name: 'Fluorine', bookingDate: randomDate() },
  { name: 'Neon', bookingDate: randomDate() },
];

/**
 * @title Tables with Material Design ripples.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-with-ripples-example',
  templateUrl: 'table-with-ripples-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatTableModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
})
export class TableWithRipplesExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'bookingDate'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: any, filter: string) => {
      console.log(data, filter, format(data.bookingDate, 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
      return (
        data.name.indexOf(filter) != -1 ||
        format(new Date(data.bookingDate), 'dd/mm/yyyy').indexOf(filter) != -1
      );
    };
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

html

```
<mat-form-field class="searchbar" appearance="outline">
  <input
    matInput
    (keyup)="applyFilter($event)"
    placeholder="Search ..."
    #input
  />
</mat-form-field>
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="bookingDate">
    <mat-header-cell mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      Booking Date
    </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      {{element.bookingDate | date : 'dd/mm/yyyy'}}
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row matRipple *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/n8pdhw?file=src%2Fexample%2Ftable-with-ripples-example.ts,src%2Fexample%2Ftable-with-ripples-example.html)

Comment: Hi , isit able to search for both name and also date? BTW, thanks for your answer, it helped me a lot.

Comment: @JiaDe please feel free to adjust the filter predicate to suit your requirement